# sql how to calculate the overlapping date

Tags: sql, oracle

Here are five renting records by one person, is there any way to check if there is any overlapping borrow period last more than 30 days among these 5 data?

For example, (01-FEB-19 20-MAR-19)and (14-FEB-19 25-MAR-19) has an overlapping over 30 days

EDIT:
And I am looking for comparing the 5 data to get the answer if there is an overlap. Because there might have other people rent the item 3 times in another 3 periods, I don't know how to iterate through the whole date range for each person and check

Thanks!!

```
    START_DAT  DATE_RETUN 
    -------------------- 
     19-FEB-19 20-FEB-19                          
     01-FEB-19 20-MAR-19                         
     14-FEB-19 25-MAR-19                         
     02-FEB-19 22-MAR-19                         
     14-FEB-19 25-FEB-19
```

Comment: Oh! sorry, I correct the pair

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You can calculate the overlap using arithmetic and just check:

```
select t.*, t2.*
from t join
     t t2
     on t.start <= t2.return - interval '30' day and
        t.return >= t.start + interval '30' day
where (least(t1.return, t.return) - greatest(t.start, t2.start)) >= 30;
```

The interval adjustments in the `on` clause are just for efficiency.

Comment: Is there any way to compare 5 records and check? I've edited my question above, hopes its more clearly. Thanks!!

Comment: And the start date and return date are the columns in the same table

Comment: @ShinYuWu - this is only looking at one table; the self-join is because you want to compare two rows in that table. This is looking at the return date of one row and the start date of another row, to see if those overlap.

Answer (score 0):

```
with test_table as (
  select 1 id, to_date('19-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from_dat,  to_date('20-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') to_dat from dual union all                          
  select 2 id, to_date('01-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from_dat,  to_date('20-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') to_dat from dual union all                               
  select 3 id, to_date('14-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from_dat,  to_date('25-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') to_dat from dual union all                                
  select 4 id, to_date('02-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from_dat,  to_date('22-03-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') to_dat from dual union all                               
  select 5 id, to_date('14-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from_dat,  to_date('25-02-2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy') to_dat from dual      
)

select id, from_dat, max(to_dat) from test_table
connect by nocycle
  PRIOR to_dat > from_dat     and 
  PRIOR from_dat < to_dat
group by id, from_dat
having max(to_dat) - from_dat > 30
order by id, from_dat
```

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL , it can be achieved as per below query:

select
p.* from
(select T.*,

datediff(day,T.START_DAT ,T.DATE_RETUN) as Overlap_days

from T)as p
where p.Overlap_days >=30